# Micronaut fails to load bean in integration test if test is run with other tests

Tags: java, testing, groovy, spock, micronaut

I have Micronaut application that uses SQLite, I created integration tests with groovy and Spock for the application. Everything works fine if Specifications are run independently, when all tests are run at once, sometimes one of the tests that uses CrudRepository fails with error:

```
Error instantiating bean of type [io.micronaut.http.server.codec.TextStreamCodec]

Message:
Bean of type [class io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment]
is a manually registered singleton that was registered with the context via
BeanContext.registerBean(..) and cannot be created directly

Path Taken:
new DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations(String dataSourceName,DataJdbcConfiguration jdbcConfiguration,DataSource dataSource,TransactionOperations transactionOperations,ExecutorService executorService,BeanContext beanContext,List codecs,DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider,RuntimeEntityRegistry entityRegistry,DataConversionService conversionService,AttributeConverterRegistry attributeConverterRegistry,SchemaTenantResolver schemaTenantResolver,JdbcSchemaHandler schemaHandler)
--> new DefaultJdbcRepositoryOperations(String dataSourceName,DataJdbcConfiguration jdbcConfiguration,DataSource dataSource,TransactionOperations transactionOperations,ExecutorService executorService,BeanContext beanContext,[List codecs],DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider,RuntimeEntityRegistry entityRegistry,DataConversionService conversionService,AttributeConverterRegistry attributeConverterRegistry,SchemaTenantResolver schemaTenantResolver,JdbcSchemaHandler schemaHandler)
--> new TextStreamCodec(ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,[ByteBufferFactory byteBufferFactory],BeanProvider codecRegistryProvider,CodecConfiguration codecConfiguration)
```

This is my base class for all of the specifications:

```java
abstract class BaseSpec extends Specification {
  @Shared
  @Inject
  protected EmbeddedServer embeddedServer

  @AutoCleanup
  @Shared
  protected ApplicationContext applicationContext

  @AutoCleanup("shutdown")
  @Shared
  protected WireMockServer wireMockServer

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  void setupSpec() {
    //Thread.sleep(500)
    preSetupSpec()
    cleanDatabase()
    WireMock.configureFor("localhost", 8090)
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().port(8090))
    wireMockServer.start()
    Unirest.setHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setConnectionManager(new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager())
        .build())
    Unirest.setObjectMapper(new com.mashape.unirest.http.ObjectMapper() {
      private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

      @Override
      <T> T readValue(String value, Class<T> valueType) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(value, valueType)
      }

      @Override
      String writeValue(Object value) {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
      }
    })
    embeddedServer = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer, "integration")
    applicationContext = embeddedServer.applicationContext
    ApplicationSettings.BASE_URL = embeddedServer.URL.toString()
    ApplicationSettings.PORT = embeddedServer.URL.getPort()
    postSetupSpec()
  }

  protected void preSetupSpec() {}

  protected void postSetupSpec() {}

  private static void cleanDatabase() {
    def parent = System.getProperty("user.dir")
    new File(parent, "build/tmp/colleague-identity-distributed.db").delete()
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  void cleanupSpec() {
    wireMockServer.stop()
  }

  void setup() {
    if (!wireMockServer.isRunning()) {
      wireMockServer.start()
    }
    wireMockServer.resetAll()
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  void stubEndpoint(StubMapping stubMapping) {
    wireMockServer.addStubMapping(stubMapping)
  }
}
```

Not always the same method fails, and what is interesting is that if I comment out just one of the database tests (not even the one that is failing) everything goes back to normal, it seems like i exceeded some kind of the threshold. Also, adding Thread.sleep in the beginning of the  the setupSpec fixes the problem.

Comment: This Github-issue suggestion may be of interest: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/1697#issuecomment-1307916860

Comment: unfortunately, i tried extending my   cleanupSpec method:
  void cleanupSpec() {
    wireMockServer.stop()
    embeddedServer.stop()
    applicationContext.stop()
    Awaitility.await().until{
      !wireMockServer.isRunning() && !embeddedServer.isRunning() && !applicationContext.isRunning()
    }
  }
without any results, only hardcoding Thread.sleep(500) (or more milis) helps

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting a sample Micronaut project on GitHub would enable non-Micronaut useres among the Spock experts here to reproduce your problem and helping you. Thank you.